# Pandas - How can I make every value within a column NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to clear all the data from a column within my dataframe but keep the dataframe exactly the same.

The Excel equivalent of this would be to select all the data in a column beneath the header and right-click "Clear Contents".

I tried this:

```
test = df.replace(to_replace=df('Column Name'), value=NaN)
```

but got an error stating:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I don't know what that means or how to think about changing my code.

Comment: Why not just `df['Column Name']` = NaN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `df['Column Name'] = NaN`, [simples](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl545RF6dXA)